# Magento 2: format var invoice.created_at

Tags: magento2, pdf, variables, custom-variable

I'm using [EaDesgin/magento2-pdf-generator2](https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-pdf-generator2) to format the customer's invoice. This works nice. But in this template I use the magento 2 variable **{{var invoice.created_at}}**, what gives me the ugly format `'yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s'`.

I want to reformat this date. 
Maybe I could add a custom variable (not with backend, there I cannot use PHP functions), or a filter to `invoice.created_at`. Where can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a new function to Model/Order/Invoice.php:

```
public function getInvoiceDate(){
        $cdate = $this->getCreatedAt();
        $invoiceDate = date('d. M. Y', strtotime($cdate));
        return $invoiceDate;
    }
```

Then you can use {{var invoice.invoice_date}} to display the formatted date.

Tested with Magento 2.2.3 and EADesign Invoice PDF Generator 1.2.2